# Stati Schengen visa

Tags: visas, schengen, italy, netherlands, amsterdam

I had a stati Schengen visa applied from Italy embassy in uk. Its a type c stati Schengen visa.

As of now my plan has changed, instead of going to Italy got changed to Netherlands. So can i go to Netherlands instead of going to Italy as a first entry. Will be any problem?

Please help, Thanks.

Comment: The place you enter the Schengen Area does not matter. The main destination for your trip does.

Comment: My Schengen visa expires in end of this month, on visa got number of entries is -1. So, not going to Italy, now the main destination is Netherlands. Will there be any problem at boarding time?

Comment: At boarding time unlikely, for the airline the only thing that counts is that you have a visa and that it’s valid. You **may** have an issue at passport control though, or for future visa applications (as you applied for a visa from one country and then used it to go to another), but the jury is probably still out on this one (enforcement varies a lot).

Comment: Thanks for your message, on visa i got stati Schengen, it counts all Schengen countries?
Previously i have book to italy and due to delay of visa delivery i have lost my flight tickets. Now i have got few days. Instead i have changed it to Netherlands. If any asks at passport control can I explain my situation will that be ok?